# Module object is not callable, while trying to overcome cycle import

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter, import

I have an object-oriented Tkinter app and I need to import one instance, but cycle import would happen. So I tried just `import ModuleName` instead of `from ModuleName import ModuleName`, but I get the `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable, does anyone know how to solve this?
If you need any more information, I'm here to provide it.

Comment: You have to post more code. I think that somewhere in your code you run `ModuleName()` which is causing the error

Comment: Yes, I run `ModuleName(parameters)`. Is that the problem? Am I doing it wrongly when I just `import ModuleName`?

Comment: change that line to `ModuleName.ModuleName(parameters)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by [@TheLizzard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11106801/thelizzard)

change that line to `ModuleName.ModuleName(parameters)`